# Make a backup of absolutely all

Tags: windows, backup

My computer is giving me some problems with the battery and I'm thinking to send it to the factory. (My computer is an ASUS with Windows 8.1)

But I have it very configured. I have lots of programs with detailed configurations, and it would be a hard work to reset my computer or having a new one from the warranty. So I would like to make a backup of absolutelly all. I don't know if it is possible or not. It won't be enough to store the media and some other things. I want really ALL. (Including all the pc configuration, all the programs, all the modifications...) I would like to have ABSOLUTELY the same in the reseted pc or in the new one.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: If you copy the whole disc, restoring it is most straightforward. If you copy each of the partitions separately, restoration of the whole disc is more complicated, but restoration of individual partitions is easy. I suggest  using an external, bootable disc for backing up, as this makes sure of a restore mechanism if the main disc is completely erased. If you use a commercial package (or certain freeware), you get additional facilities, such as compression, and restoration of individual files or directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a System Image or a Hard Disk Image (same thing, different name).

You can do this with built-in tools, from [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/back-up-programs-system-settings-files#1TC=windows-7):

1. Open Backup and Restore by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Maintenance, and then clicking Backup and Restore.
2. In the left pane, click Create a system image, and then follow the steps in the wizard. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

You will need some big storage of course in order to take the backup.

There are 3rd party tools as well that can do this.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the hard drive before shipping the laptop for repair.  The repair does not involve the hard drive.

Otherwise, use any full-disk backup or disk cloning software.

Comment: specifics are not off topic. The OP has not asked for recommendations but you are free to make them.

Comment: Last time I sent in a laptop for repair they actually insisted that I removed the HDD before I shipped the laptop. It simply makes sense for the user (no data loss) **and** for the repair shop/factory which does not get your personal information and all the potential problems involved with that.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to make an image of the drive, as just backing up the files will not be sufficient if you have lots of programs installed (thank you, registry!).

1. Get an external hard drive.
2. Download a live boot image that you can put on a USB flash drive with cloning software. Clonezilla is a free option: http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php
3. Clone your hard drive over.
4. Send out computer for repair!
5. When the computer comes back, verify that everything's fixed, and then clone back the old image.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a Windows OS, there's no need to boot from an external drive: Windows Shadow Copy enables copying even a mounted partition. There are a number of free disk-imaging tools, such as [Macrium Reflect Free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx), [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) and [Paragon Free Edition](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/br-free/).

You can keep the image on another drive and/or export it to a cloud service -- each has advantages and disadvantages (the cloud service can lose the image; the physical HD at home could be damaged...).

It is good practice to have a backup image of your HD, *before* anything goes wrong (and verify that it is a good image, too, at least by browsing it).